# How to get a Super Table relation in PHP?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-supertable

The following code works great in a template.

```
{% set priceProduct = currentUser.priceTable.relatedTo({    
    targetElement: product.id,
    field: 'product'
}).one() %}

{{ priceProduct.price }}
```

Where priceTable is a Super Table, product.id is from an entry element (we're in loop).

'product' is an entry field in the Super Table row and 'price' is a plaintext field in the Super Table row.

How might we go about replicating this functionality in a plugin?

Craft Pro 3.0.29

Super Table 2.0.11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```php
$element = Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity()->priceTable->relatedTo([
    'targetElement' => $product->id,
    'field' => 'product'
])->one()
```

But to be honest your code in Twig should not work as expected since you only grab the query and modify it. Your output is your search criteria, not the value of an element.

Comment: Thank you. (I was so close!) Yeah, I wondered about that. Not getting a deprecation warning either. Fixed in the edit.

Comment: Nothing was deprecated, you just display the criteria of your `ElementQuery` there is nothing wrong about that, it is just not what you want